# JSONProvider Class substitute in Apache CXF 3.1.11

Tags: apache, cxf

JSONProvider class has been removed in Apache CXF 3.1.11 version.
Is there any substitute Apache had provided for JSONProvider.

package of JSONProvider was "org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json" till 3.1.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The class still exists in cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers artifact.

Comment: Thanks Dennis for your response.Please provide any link  if possible for you.

Thanks

Comment: I am looking for this class in Apache CXF 3.1.11 version.The reply you have told is "cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers" was upto apache cxf 3.1.1 or may be above that but not in  CXF 3.1.11 version

Comment: If you download http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers/3.1.11/cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers-3.1.11.jar the class is still there